# Cytoscape app 3.9.1 does not respect label text justification settings

Tags: cytoscape

As shown in the image, the justification in the settings (right) is not respected in the rendering (left). How does one make this work?

[image: justification in the settings is not respected in the rendering]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, this will be fixed in 3.10.

Comment: Can you consolidate your three answers into one?

Answer (score 0):

OK, an update on this.  It turns out that this is by design (and I certainly won't defend the design).  If you add a newline: '\n', then justification will work as expected.  The newline can be anywhere in the string, but it has to be there.  Don't know why, but it's pretty explicit in the code that if there isn't a newline, justification is forced to be centered.